# Ruby SQL Server and Do blocks

Tags: ruby, sql-server, tiny-tds

I have the following code:

```
sql = "select Board_Name AS 'Board Name', COUNT(Board_Name) AS 'Count' from dbo.TABLE  GROUP BY Board_Name"
result = client.execute(sql)
result.each do |row|
  binfo = [ label: row['Board Name'], value: row['Count'] ]
  send_event('ticketsbyboard', { items: binfo })
end
```

I'm trying to get all of the rows passed to the send_event as one array, instead of just one row at a time.

Comment: I don't know MsSQL client, but have you tried `result.to_a`?

Comment: @neil-slater Yes, i tried that initially, however i need the array to have the "label" tag which i set in the send_event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a map:

```
binfo = result.map do |row|
  { label: row['Board Name'], value: row['Count'] }
end
send_event('ticketsbyboard', { items: binfo })
```

If your `result` object doesn't respond directly to `map`, just use `result.to_a.map`